# How to solve admin.E040 in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token

I have installed REST framework token authentication in Django and every time I run the local server it gives me an error.

```
class 'rest_framework.authtoken.admin.TokenAdmin'>: (admin.E040)
UserModelAdmin must define "search_fields",
because it's referenced by TokenAdmin.autocomplete_fields.
```

Comment: please provide example code of your api views

Comment: The solution was provided. No need for API Views, thanks for responding.

Comment: Yeah, I can't post a code in this question because after I have installed DRF, the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding this field in admin.py

```py
search_fields = ('email',)
```

then

`manage.py migrate`